# Retrieving dynamic value with selenium webdriver, python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am aware that there already exists similar threads about this. However, when trying previously suggested methods to retrieve my specific dynamic table value, all I am getting is either a nbsp value or something cryptic like `"1a207feb-8080-4ff0-..."`

**What I am trying to do:**

Get the current table value for euro/oz value for gold from [here](https://www.bullionvault.com/gold-price-chart.do). I "inspected" the page and got the `xpath (//*[@id="bullionPriceTable"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/span)`

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.bullionvault.com/gold-price-chart.do")

xpath = '//*[@id="bullionPriceTable"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/span'

select=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
print(select)
```

This prints:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3ade114e9f0907e4eb13deac6a264fc8", element="3a670af5-8594-4504-908a-a9bfcbac7342")>
```

which obviously is not the number I was looking for.

I've also experimented with using get_attribute('innerHtml') and .text on the webElement, but to no avail. What am I missing here? Am I just not encoding this value correctly, or am I extracting from the wrong source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Wait for the page to load then try to get the `innerHTML` like the following example*

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

chrome_browser.get("https://www.bullionvault.com/gold-price-chart.do")

time.sleep(2)

select = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[@id='bullionPriceTable']/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/span"
).get_attribute("innerHTML")

print(select)
```

> **`€1,450.98`**

Answer (score 1):

To extract the table value for euro/oz value for gold i.e. the text  **€1,452.47** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

  driver.get('https://www.bullionvault.com/gold-price-chart.do#')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cookies-warning-buttons']//a[text()='Accept']"))).click()
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Live Gold Price']"))))
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//th[text()='Gold Price per Ounce']//following-sibling::td[3]/span[@data-currency='EUR']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  €1,456.30
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver.get('https://www.bullionvault.com/gold-price-chart.do#')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cookies-warning-buttons']//a[text()='Accept']"))).click()
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Live Gold Price']"))))
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//th[text()='Gold Price per Ounce']//following-sibling::td[3]/span[@data-currency='EUR']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  €1,456.30
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

This solution does not compile though due to "EC" not being defined. Could you clarify what EC is and where you retrieved it?

Best regards

Comment: @paxel Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: It seems the first alternative produces a console output of "nbsp", and the second alternative prints nothing at all.

I have initiated driver as: 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")